# Artoolkit does not load textures in OS X

Tags: macos, augmented-reality, flartoolkit

Hello i am using the latest version of artoolkit, and succesfully compiled simplevrml, but it doesn't show any textures not even the ones in the bud_B example.

Does anyone have a similar experience or problem or have solved this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mac os x textures as gif don't work only png and jpg